# How to Parse Complete XML into a string using DOM PARSER?

Tags: java, xml, domparser

For example:

If I pass tagValue=1 then it should return complete xml1 as a string to me String input is in some function.

`String input = "<1><xml1></xml1></1><2><xml2></xml2><2>.......<10000><xml10000></xml10000></10000‌​>";
String output = "<xml1></xml1>";   // for tagValue=1;`

Comment: What is XML input and what did you try in code?

Comment: wait for a minute...this is not proper xml ..i am editing

Comment: try input.replaceAll("<xml1>", "")

Comment: All you have done in output is remove one tag- >XML1. I am not clear on what you want to do. If you already have XML as a string, then removing the top tag is just a matter of doing some string processing. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: actually, parsing is using DOM parser not just a string

Comment: How do you get the xml? Reading from a file, getting from a stream?

Comment: XML file having 'n' number of xml's....For example:   <1><xml1></xml1></1><2><xml2></xml2><2>.......<10000></10000>. If I pass tag=1 then it should return complete xml1 as a string to me.

Comment: You can do this trivially with XPath, or, if your requirements are more complex than stated, with XSLT.

Comment: how it can be done using DOM Parser?

Comment: Do you have a root element? And can you paste some code for what you have tried so far? This should be possible to handle.

Comment: It will be difficult to post in comment as there is module wise code....

Comment: @MohdFaizan *Why* should it be done with a DOM parser? What do you care how it gets done? XPath and XSLT will work with either a SAX or a DOM parser.

Comment: Half of the work already done in DOM ....and it's to be forcefully done under DOM Parser

Comment: I don't know what 'forceully done under DOM parser' means, and I'm not sure you do either, but the parsing technique is a minor issue here. You've been told several times about XPath and XSLT, and you haven't even responded to that. If someone is dictating DOM and nothing else to you, they are not sufficiently well-informed to do so, and you can tell them that from me.

Answer (score 0):

If the xml has a root element then it is doable
1. Parse the XML using dom parser.
2. Iterate through each node
3. Find the desired node.
4. Write the node in a different xml using transform

Sample code
Step 1: I used XML as a string, you can read from file.

```
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                     .newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is =  new InputSource(new StringReader(uri));
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

2. Iterate through each node

   if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {

   ```
               printNote(doc.getChildNodes(), doc);

           }
   ```
3. Please put in your logic to iterate thorugh the nodes and find the right child node which you want to process.
4. Write back as xml. Here assumption is that tempNode is the one you want to write as XML.

   TransformerFactory tFactory =
                       TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                       Transformer transformer;
                       try {
                           transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

   ```
                   DOMSource source = new DOMSource(tempNode);
                   StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                   transformer.transform(source, result);
   ```

Comment: for each <xml></xml> ....<1></1> is a root element but the problem is file/string having large number of such xmls...and at a time I need only one <xml></xml>..

Comment: The master xml should have a root element, then each child node can be processed easily.

Comment: Can you share me the piece of code what you tried ? and for master there can be one one master tag <XMLFILE><1><xml1></xml1></1><2><xml2></xml2></2></XMLFILE>...

Comment: Code is shared in the answer. I have tested and it works. The complete XML is imported as a document. Then you parse on its nodes, each node being a separate xml. This child node should be written as done in step 4. Please try it out.

Comment: its working but the issue is it appends more content by itself ----"javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult@60292cb9" at the end of xml and <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in the start of xml

Comment: Well it did add  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> for me, not the javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult@60292cb9, but even if it does, why don't you convert it to string and remove these 2 lines?

Comment: I am not saying that I cannot do this...I  am just saying that these lines are added ...but thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

You are not parsing XML, you are parsing a String, a replace should be enough in your particular case

```
   String input = "<xml1><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from<heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend</body></note><xml1>";
    input = input.replace("<xml1>", "");
```

Comment: this is not the string ....I am having XML file containing 1000s of XML files, now to parse XML file using tagname=1. For example: <1><xml1></xml1></1><2><xml2></xml2><2> and so on. If I pass tag=1 then it should return complete xml1.

Comment: check this:
 https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

otherwise you can use JAXB

Comment: what case? there is no case nor clear description in your question, there are thousands of way to achieve this so please be precise when you ask a question